# How am I mis-using NotThrowAsync

Tags: c#, async-await, fluent-assertions

I used FluentAssertions; it's great! :) I particularly like using the `.Invoking().Should().Throw<Exception>()` pattern it provides.

I wrote this line in my test:

```cs
myObject.Invoking(r => r.SomeAsyncFunc()).Should().NotThrowAsync();
```

Where `.SomeAsyncFunc` is declared using the `async` keyword and makes use of the `await` keyword internally.

And it all passed, and I was very happy. And then I thought to verify that the test was doing what I thought it did, so I added code to force `SomeAsyncFunc()` to immediately throw. (before hitting any `await` keywords).

It still passed. This made me sad :(

I tried the following formulations, all of which also passed:

```cs
myObject.Invoking(r => r.SomeAsyncFunc()).Should().NotThrowAsync();
myObject.Invoking(async r => await r.SomeAsyncFunc()).Should().NotThrowAsync();
myObject.Awaiting(r => r.SomeAsyncFunc()).Should().NotThrowAsync();
myObject.Awaiting((Func<MyObject, Task>)(async r => await r.SomeAsyncFunc())).Should().NotThrowAsync();
```

Whereas is if I do this, then it DOES work ... but that feels very wrong!

```cs
myObject.Invoking(r => r.SomeAsyncFunc()).Should().NotThrow();
```

**What have I mis-understood?**

Comment: Btw, the line you say 'works', doesn't really. The method returns a Task which likely hasn't executed.. But sans an await in the test it wouldn't throw anyways (unless you throw any exceptions prior to the first await of the method)

Answer (score 3):

I'm a moron.

`.NotThrowAsync()` is itself an `async` method, and thus needs to be `await`ed to work properly.

To allow that I needed to make my test `async` too:

```cs
//    |*This bit*|
public async Task SomeAsyncFunc_UnderRelevantConditions_DoesNotThrow()
{
    // ... Do Setup.
    
    await myObject.Invoking(r => r.SomeAsyncFunc()).Should().NotThrowAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to combine the right things. So either use the synchronous version:

```cs
myObject.Awaiting(r => r.SomeAsyncFunc()).Should().NotThrow();
```

or go all the away `async`:

```cs
await myObject.Awaiting(r => r.SomeAsyncFunc()).Should().NotThrowAsync();
```

Comment: What is the difference between `.Invoking` and `.Awaiting`, the docs don't really seem to spell it out?